# Access for Merging Pull requests : GITHUB

Tags: github

Can someone let me know how I can give/control access of merge PR for certain users for a repository.

Our GIT Flow developers will be creating a feature branch from MASTER in local repository and then push this branch to remote and then created Pull request.

Then Owner of the repository will review and Merge Pull request.
I tried giving READ access by adding developers to COLLOBORATOR but users are not able to push their feature branch.

Let me know how I can achieve above GIT Flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally Got it.

We can achieve this by adding developer as "COLLOBORATOR" for repository with "WRITE" Permission. Then, in settings add the branch as "Protected Branch" in this way developer will be able to push their feature branch and at the same time he will not be able to do changes to Protected Branch (Master/Develop).

Hope this helps to someone!

Answer (score 1):

You can add these users as collaborators. From github's official [doc](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/):

> Collaborator access on a repository owned by a user account
>
> Collaborators on a private repository can:
>
> Push to (write), pull from (read), and fork (copy) the repository,
>       Apply labels and milestones,
>       Open, close, re-open, and assign issues,
>       Edit and delete comments on commits, pull requests, and issues,
>       **Merge and close pull requests**,
>       Send pull requests from forks of the repository,
>       Create and edit Wikis,
>       Create and edit Releases,
>       Remove themselves as collaborators on the repository

(the emphasis is mine)

Comment: I tried giving READ access by adding developers to COLLOBORATOR but users are not able to push their feature branch. i need them to push their local branch but they should not be able to do changes directly to master

Comment: Ah, now I understood your problem. I don't think it's possible, but you can have a remote repo for each developer, and then create pull requests from there to the main repo.